# How to handle many different input binary message types

Tags: c++, design-patterns, io

I have a device that I am communicating with by sending and receiving a particular binary packet structure. The device has a somewhat well defined API, but there are over 100 possible message types that it can return. What is a good design to use to handle the processing of these different message types?

Here is an example in pseudocode, I am ignoring framing, and checksum bytes to make it clearer.

```
// I receive this message, where 0x00 indicates the device status,
//and each other byte is a particular error or status
message = [0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x04]
// The next message I receive, where 0x10 indicates system time, 
// and the rest of the fields are the integer clock seconds of the device.
message = [0x10, 0x00, 0x32, 0xFF, 0x8E]
// 100 other message types....
```

As you can see, each message I receive needs to be processed slightly different, has different meanings. I originally was going to use a gigantic switch statement `case 0x00: process_errors() case 0x10: process_time()` but I was curious if there a better design that I could use to increase flexibility of adding new message types, better useability, etc.

Comment: Do you know all the possible messages at compile time? if yes, you can just create a map and whenever you receive a message look for the handler function in the map... If not, then you can have a structure in which you can register handlers for a given message and its handler function, or something along theses lines.

Comment: Currently what is your difficulty when adding new message types?

Comment: For embedded systems, I recommend using a table of message byte and pointer to function.  The table can be built during compile time and stored in read-only memory.  A map has to be created during run-time and uses dynamic memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using TLV (Tag Length Value) implementation. It is good for processing stream of data.

**Tag** - This will be a byte of data(as per your example) which identifies the type of message that follows. For this to be utilized, you should before hand be aware of which message type has how many data. For instance, in case of 0x00 (device status) you should now beforehand that the next 3 bytes are the data.

**Length** - The length of data bytes

**Value** - The actual data

**Here is what you can do:**
1) Prepare a map of the Tag and Length of different messages that your system supports.
2) Receive bytes of data continuously.
3) Read the 1st byte (this will be the tag) and determine what type of message it is. In your case this will give you 0x00, 0x10 etc.
4) Refer to your map of tag and length information. You will determine how many bytes of data you need to read further.
5) Once you read the data portion, your receiver should be ready to receive next message (ready to read next tag)

This is all about reading the messages. Once you have the message and its data with you, you can use it as you like. For instance, in addition to the length of message corresponding to a Tag, you can register a function also. This will let you call a particular function along with the parameters required by it.

**Device Status**

```
Data Tag = 00  
Data Length = 03  
Data Value =  01 01 04
```

**System time**

```
Data Tag = 10  
Data Length = 04  
Data Value =  00 32 FF 8E
```